# JAX-RS Get request 404 not found

Tags: get, jax-rs, http-status-code-404

I have been struggling for a while now trying to find the solution to my problem.
The following things I have:

```
@ApplicationPath("/api/v1")
public class App extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(MoocAPI.class);
        classes.add(Authentication.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

And the MoocAPI.class is:

```
@Path("moocs")
public class MoocAPI {

    /**
     * Retrieves moocs from the database
     * @return the list of moocs as a JSON.
     */
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getMoocs() {
        List<Mooc> moocs = MoocMapper.getMoocs();
        return Response.ok(moocs).build();
    }
}
```

So the problem is, once I start the server, it will open the index at localhost:8080/webapp which works fine. Then when I goto /webapp/api/v1/moocs it should return a list. But instead I get a 404 not found. I can not figure out why this is doing it.

Comment: What server are you using? Can you should your project dependencies?

Comment: Alright so I fixed it, for some reason I had to the Produces mediatype at the main path aswell.